# Mix react prop with href html tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react.js and JavaScript. I've to pass two phone numbers in href tag -

```
phoneListHTML={[
                "<a href='tel:{phoneNumber}'>{phoneNumber}</a>".replace('{phoneNumber}', support.expPhone),
                "<a href='tel:{phoneNumber}'>{phoneNumber}</a>".replace('{phoneNumber}', support.expPhoneInternational),
                ]}
```

The "hyperlink text" is not getting replaced but actual "hyperlink clickthrough text" is replaced.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the (relevant) code it's hard to see why you're doing this. Why not `map` over the data in React to produce the correct rendered HTML?

Comment: I'm passing this as argument to React component. @Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead which allows for global replace (*all occurrences*) with the `g` flag.

SO

```js
phoneListHTML={[
      "<a href='tel:{phoneNumber}'>{phoneNumber}</a>".replace(/{phoneNumber}/g, support.expPhone),
      "<a href='tel:{phoneNumber}'>{phoneNumber}</a>".replace(/{phoneNumber}/g, support.expPhoneInternational),
                ]}
```

alternatively you could use template literals

```js
phoneListHTML={[
      `<a href="tel:${support.expPhone}">${support.expPhone}</a>`),
      `<a href="tel:${support.expPhoneInternational}">${support.expPhoneInternational}</a>`),
                ]}
```

Comment: This is helpful.

Comment: @Prakhar where is this html to be used ? If it will be displayed in the browser you might be better to use actual components `<a href={`tel:${support.expPhone}`}>{support.expPhone}</a>`

Comment: This is for browser but I'm passing raw HTML to old component - <CustomerSupport
confirmationNumber={support.itineraryNumber}
phoneListHTML={[
"<a href='tel:{phoneNumber}'>{phoneNumber}</a>".replace(/{phoneNumber}/g, support.expPhone),
"<a href='tel:{phoneNumber}'>{phoneNumber}</a>".replace(/{phoneNumber}/g, support.expPhoneInternational),
]}

customerSupportText={support.expSupportInfoText}
/>

Comment: phoneListHTML expects HTML tags (phone array) and when I put like above without inverted-commas it shows [object, object].

Comment: I see, added an alternative way (*using template literals*). Also you might want to eventually refactor that component to work without expecting html..

Comment: Lateral worked - much easier to understand and maintain. You're right - old shared component - needs refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you shouldn't be passing down raw HTML like that. You should be passing down objects/arrays containing data and allow your components to render the HTML based on that data.

```js
// Support information
const support = { phone: '123', international: '+44 123' };

// Render the App component
// passing in the support object as props
ReactDOM.render(
  <App support={support} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

// App accepts props and returns some JSX
// which contains the Support component
// with the support object passed to it in its props
function App(props) {
  return (
   <main>
     <h3>Support</h3>
     <Support support={props.support} />
   </main>
  )
}

// Returns JSX with the completed information
function Support({ support }) {
  const { phone, international } = support;
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={phone}>{phone}</a><br/>
      <a href={international}>{international}</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```